# Cargar imagen creada en PHP directo a la Base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, imagen

Estoy utilizando la librería [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) para generar un código QR que se guarda como imagen png en una ruta específica. El problema es que no sé cómo guardar la imagen generada directamente en la base de datos.

Cabe mencionar que el archivo PHP que utilizo ya recibe datos de un formulario por post y los datos que obtengo del formulario los utilizo para generar el QR.

Este es el código para generar el QR:

```
$dir ='../img/QR';//direccion donde se guarda la imagen de QR
if (!file_exists($dir)) {//si no existe la carpeta
    mkdir($dir);}//creamos la carpeta

$filename = $dir."$nombre".".png";//definimos la ruta y nombre del archivo para despues mostrarlo
$dias_acceso_QR =$Lunes.$Martes.$Miercoles.$Jueves.$Viernes.$Sabado.$Domingo;//obtenemos la cadena de numeros 01234567
$diasQR = dias_acceso_QR($dias_acceso_QR);//utilizamos la funcion para cambiar los numeros por el dia al que corresponden
$accesoQR = SI_NO_QR($acceso); //cambiamos 1=si y 0=no
$estatusQR = SI_NO_QR($estatus);//cambiamos 1=si y 0=no

$size = 5;//tamaño de la imagen QR
$level = 'M';//calidad del qr L=LOW,M=media,Q,H=High
$framesize=2;//ancho marco blanco del qr

//juntamos todo en el contenido
$contenido= "Nombre personal de confianza: $nombre\nOcupación: $ocupacion\nDias de Acceso: $diasQR\nHora de entrada: $timein\nHora de salida: $timeout\nAcceso Permitido: $accesoQR\nDentro del inmueble: $estatusQR\nTeléfono: $tel";

QRcode::png($contenido,$filename,$level,$size,$framesize);//se genera el QR
//echo '<img src="'.$filename.'"/> ';//impime el qr
```

Este es el código con el que agrego a la BD los datos del formulario

```
//agregamos datos a la BD
$statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO personalconfianza(idPersonalConfianza, Nombre_personal_confianza, Ocupacion_personal_confianza,Acceso_dias_personal_confianza, Hora_entrada_personal_confianza,Hora_salida_personal_confianza, Foto_ident_personal_confianza,Codigo_QR_personal_confianza, Acceso_personal_confianza,Estatus_ubic_personal_confianza,      Telefono_contacto_personal_confianza,Clasificacion_personal_confianza,Visible_personal_confianza,Residente_idResidente) VALUES (NULL,:nombre,:ocupacion,:dias_acceso,:timein,:timeout,:foto,:QR,:acceso,:estatus,:tel,:estrella,:visible,:idResidente)');

$statement->execute(array(
        ":nombre" => $nombre,
        ":ocupacion" => $ocupacion,
        ":dias_acceso" => $dias_acceso,
        ":timein" => $timein,
        ":timeout" => $timeout,
        ":foto" => $foto,
        ":QR" => $filename,
        ":acceso" => $acceso,
        ":estatus" => $estatus,
        ":tel" => $tel,
        ":estrella" => $estrella,
        ":visible" => $visible,
        ":idResidente" => $idResidente
));
```

`":QR" => $filename` en una página leí que se podía subir la imagen metiendo la dirección de la imagen pero al intentar abrirla desde la base de datos no aparece nada.

La idea es que después de subir todos los datos se muestren en una tabla y pueda visualizar la imagen del QR como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la primera fila si se muestra el QR porque lo subí desde phpmyadmin, el segundo fue con el código que muestro anteriormente

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no aparece nada? ¿Qué valor hay en la base de datos después de hacer el insert? ¿cómo lo lees/utilizas después? ¿se guardó la imagen QR bien y está en el directorio indicado?´

Comment: al parecer se guarda la dirección /img/QR/jose.png  porque hay un archivo blob de 17B (muy poco para una imagen) y le doy click al archivo blob y me descarga un .bin que abro con un explorador y me sale que si quiero abrir el archivo pero de ahi no pasa. Anteriormente he subido fotos mediante formularios y al hacer este proceso si se muestra la imagen que subi

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es almacenar la ruta donde se guarda la imagen y no la imagen en sí. ¿por qué no pruebas cambiando el campo de la base de datos de `BLOB` a `varchar`?

Comment: El título y la pregunta en si son confusos. Qué quieres hacer realmente?  ¿Guardar la imagen la base de datos o guardar la ruta de la imagen la base de datos u la imagen en un directorio?

Comment: Quiero guardar la imagen de QR (generada en php) en la base de datos (en un campo blob), para después mostrarla en una tabla (edite mi pregunta original y agregue una foto)

Comment: aunque respeto la idea de guardar un QR en bbdd, no la comparto. Lo correcto (segun creo) seria guardar la url de la imagen del QR. O en este caso y de forma más util, guardar el valor de ese QR en la bbdd, y luego cuando lo necesites generas dicho QR con su valor y lo muestras. Vas a ahorrar espacio en bbdd y es más optimo generar al vuelo dicho QR, porque si luego vas a cambiarlo, con solo variar el valor lo tienes.

Comment: Revisando tu QR, veo aun más util no guardar el QR, ya que cualquier cambio de tus datos (nombre  personal, ocupacion, dias, horas, acceso, telefono) cambia el valor de tu QR. Te recomendaria generarlo con los datos que tienes.

Comment: Me gusta la idea de no guardar la imagen del QR sino los datos, gracias por la idea.